# titlesec with the explicit option messes up toc title

Tags: xetex, titlesec, titletoc

When using `titlesec` with the option `explicit` the toc title "Contents" is formatted using settings from the  (where the explicit #1 parameter must be used). I think the MWE shows it all.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
[block] 
{\Large}
{\thechapter}
{10pt}
{some fancy formatting using tikz #1}
[]

\titlecontents{chapter}
[20mm]
{\normalsize}
{\contentslabel{20mm}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentsmargin{7.5mm}\filright \contentspage}
[]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapX}
\chapter{chapY}

\end{document}
```

How can this be prevented?

Comment: Yes, of course: `\tableofcontents` issues `\chapter*{\contentsname}`. Maybe you want an alternate `\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}...` for unnumbered chapters. I see no messing up, in other words, but only the expected behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with using the `explicit` option. You have to add a `\titleformat` for unnumbered chapters, e.g.

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{}
{}
{0pt}
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries #1}
```

MWE

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}
[block]
{\Large}
{\thechapter}
{10pt}
{some fancy formatting using tikz #1}
[]   

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{}
{}
{0pt}
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries #1}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[20mm]
{\normalsize}
{\contentslabel{20mm}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentsmargin{7.5mm}\filright \contentspage}
[]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapX}
\chapter{chapY}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: In general, I discourage using the `explicit` option; it's better to define a one parameter macro, say `\fancysettingwithtikz` and using it in the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat`. The argument will automatically be supplied.

Comment: thanks. Adding this extra piece of code solved the issue. It is my misunderstanding of titlesec functionality. I was under the impression all my chapters/sections have a number, and did not see any relation of the titlesec chapter formatting configurations vs. the actual toc formatting (which you could do with titletoc or leave it up to latex).

Comment: @user2263306 You're welcome. Anyway, try to avoid using the `explicit` option when no strictly needed, as egreg warns in his comment. :-)